# Meaning of parameters in sudoers file in RedHat

Tags: linux, sudoers

HI can you tell me what is the meaning of each and every parameter meaning of this line of sudoers file in RedHat machine?

```
steve       CSNETS = (operator) /usr/local/op_commands/
```

I know first parameter is user name. However I confuse meaning about other parameters. Different sites give different answer for it.

Comment: Have you checked the manual? Try `man sudoers` in your terminal.

Comment: yes. but I didn't able to understand

Answer (score 1):

```
steve       CSNETS =    (operator)                /usr/local/op_commands/
  ^           ^             ^                                 ^              
username    hostname  execute commands as operator  path name to commands
```

[Read the manual](http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html) for more details, you can focus on "Runas_Spec".

Best regards,